# Predefined CRS and Custom CRS problem with Borneo projection

Tags: qgis

I loaded a shapefile layer into QGIS and assigned to CRS of EPSG:29873 (Timbalai 1948/ RSO Borneo (m))

[image]

I copied the Proj4 parameters from EPSG:29873 (above) and create a custom user defined coordinate systems (as below), later I intend to add in false easting and northing of 2 mil / 5 mil.

```
+proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31582047222222 +k=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65 +ellps=evrstSS +towgs84=-533.4,669.2,-52.5,0,0,4.28,9.4 +units=m +no_defs
```

[image]
[image]

Before modification (adding false easting and northing), in QGIS, I inserted a shp layer (same source) twice but assigned them to two different CRS for testing (one to EPSG:29873, and the other one to user defined USER:100001, Basemap using Bing Aerial with project CSR to EPSG:3857 WGS84/Pseudo Mercator). the result displayed quite surprisingly. the EPSG:298873 CRS locate the shp file correctly but NOT the user defined custom CRS (300+++ Km toward north from the correct one)! In fact they should displayed at the same location right, seeing that they are using the same Proj4 parameters!!!

Did I create the custom CRS wrongly?
[image]

Comment: Can you save the shapefile in the user CRS, open the .prj file in a text editor, and insert its content here?

Comment: PROJCS["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Natural_Origin",GEOGCS["GCS_Everest (Sabah & Sarawak)",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["evrstSS",6377298.556,300.8017]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Hotine_Oblique_Mercator_Azimuth_Natural_Origin"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",4],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",115],PARAMETER["azimuth",53.31582047222222],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.99984],PARAMETER["false_easting",590476.87],PARAMETER["false_northing",442857.65],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Original Shp prj. as below: PROJCS["Timbalai_1948_RSO_Borneo_Meters",GEOGCS["GCS_Timbalai_1948",DATUM["D_Timbalai_1948",SPHEROID["Everest_Definition_1967",6377298.556,300.8017]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Rectified_Skew_Orthomorphic_Natural_Origin"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",0.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.99984],PARAMETER["Azimuth",53.31582047908623],PARAMETER["Longitude_Of_Center",115.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Center",4.0],PARAMETER["XY_Plane_Rotation",53.13010235415598],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]

Comment: At first glance, the Datum D_Timbalai_1948 is missing. So you might have lost the +towgs84 parameters. Also, the projection parameters are different. Is the newly saved Shapefile displaced as well?

Comment: Which shapefile aligns with Openlayers background, if project CRS is set to EPSG:3857?

Comment: You appear to have replaced a latitude and longitude of center with a false easting and false northing. They are not equivalent. This makes it clear that you did *not* proceed as described in the question: these coordinate system specifications are *not* copies of each other with "the same parameters." Why don't you start over from the beginning, as described in your question, and see what happens?

Comment: No, it's the other way round: the "original" shapefile has missing false easting and northing, but it has a "Datum". Lat/Lon of center is at 4/115 in both cases.

Comment: @AndreJoost Yes, the newly saved shapefile displaced as well. but if re-assigned to EPSG:29873, it will be back to the desired place. so i assumed i did not create the user defined CRS correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the same as you did, and could not replicate the error. But encountered that Qgis sometimes uses another CRS than that stored in the prj file. So take care which CRS is applied to the loaded layers. I did some grids in both 29873 and user defined (red), and they match perfectly.

Here
http://www.georeference.org/forum/t96710 you find test road.zip data with the same prj file as yours, and that offsets to Google imagery only about 20 metres.

---

**EDIT**

There are some differences in the proj strings I and you are using:

my QGIS Master 29873:

> +proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31582047222222 +k=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65 +gamma=53.13010236111111 +ellps=evrstSS +towgs84=-533.4,669.2,-52.5,0,0,4.28,9.4 +units=m +no_defs

LUKIP QGIS Lisboa 29873:

> +proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31582047222222 +k=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65 +ellps=evrstSS +towgs84=-533.4,669.2,-52.5,0,0,4.28,9.4 +units=m +no_defs

SR 29873:

> +proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31582047222222 +k=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65 +ellps=evrstSS +units=m +no_defs

Your proj string misses the gamma value. Thats the crazy thing about omerc: The projection axis is not a meridian (as most other merc projections), but with an angle to it. The coordinates are finally reprojected to have north up again. The SR string is even older, and misses the +towgs84 also.

The grid with my proj string in black and yours in red looks like this:

[image: Borneo grid comparison]

You have taken the proj string from QGIS Lisboa, probably Windows standalone installer. There is a bug in that installer, which prevents QGIS from synchronizing with the built-in GDAL projection database. Installing in a path without blanks (that is not in `C:\Programs (x86)\` solves that issue, or using OSGEO4W installer. Master is only available with the later one.

Earlier versions of GDAL had a different way of handling the omerc projection, which was found to be inaccurate, and replaced with the handling of the gamma value. But now you have a new version of GDAL built inside QGIS, but the old proj string in the not-updated CRS database.

You can modify the CRS database, called srs.db, with spatialite GUI (because its a sqlite database as well), or reinstall QGIS to have correct handling of EPSG:29873.

Comment: i insert few dumpscreen into original post to show how i create the custom user defined CRS. please kindly help to inspect and hopefully i get the right procedure to do it.

Comment: i try using [spatial reference tool](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/29873/html/) to generate the Proj4 format for Timbalai 1948/ RSO Borneo (m) `+proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31582047222222 +k=0.99984 +x_0=590476.87 +y_0=442857.65 +ellps=evrstSS +units=m +no_defs` and assigned the shapefile to this new custom CRS. the output still cannot match the two CRS together. the new user defined CRS using spatial reference tool still go to North 300,+++Km

Comment: OK, no I got the differences, see my extended answer. By the way, your proj string has the correct false easting and northing already!

Comment: thanks for all the help, my layers locating at correct position now. for the 2000000, 5000000 false easting and northing, i modified your Proj4 format to +x_0=2590476.87 +y_0=5442857.65 and it display correctly as well.

Comment: any good tool apart from [spatial reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/upload/) to generate the proj4 string from WKT format for use in GIS FOSS?

Comment: Have a look at gdalsrsinfo.